# Creating a tabular display when displaying outputs

Tags: c, display, tabular-form

I want to create a tabular display that has a name, ID, course year and GPA and have the spacing in the name and courses to be based on the longest name and course there is

I tried using align specifiers, but it can be hard to just assume that the longest name available would be the same each time the program is run

Comment: Use a library, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Comment: If you cannot hard-code the column size then you have to process the data to figure out what it should be, right?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate through your data to figure out the width of each column:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX(a, b) (a) >= (b) ? (a) : (b)

int main() {
    char *data[] = {"what", "is", "the", "secret?" };
    size_t w = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof data / sizeof *data; i++) {
        size_t tmp = strlen(data[i]);
        w = MAX(w, tmp);
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof data / sizeof *data; i++)
        printf("| %*s |\n", (int) w, data[i]);
}
```

and here is the corresponding output:

```
|    what |
|      is |
|     the |
| secret? |
```

Comment: If that answered your question please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it so we know you are all set.